# Java regex pattern to be used in FileNameFilter for excluding specific files

Tags: java, regex

I want to exclude all the files in a directory having file name in the form of `[.*].[a-z]{3,4}.bak`. If the filename is for e.g "hello.txt" or "hello.xlsx" then it should be included. I have created a pattern `^([^.]+)(\\.)([a-z]{3,4})$` which seems to work correctly for my case, but I need to ensure the correctness of the above pattern. Kindly let me know if there is a better pattern to handle this scenario.

Valid Case (Files to be included):

- Hello.xls
- hello.xlsx

Invalid Case (Files to be excluded)

- hello.txt.bak
- hello.xlsx.bak

Comment: Why don't you have `.bak` at the end of regex? Also please post some valid/invalid samples.

Comment: Use tools for [regex checking](https://regex101.com/r/HBVs2p/1) and write `unit tests`.

Comment: Did you consider something like `filename.endsWith('.bak')` ?

Comment: @khelwood The FileNameFilter implementation uses name.matches and cannot be changed

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi
Valid Case (Files to be included)
Hello.xls
hello.xlsx

Invalid Case (Files to be excluded)
hello.txt.bak
hello.xlsx.bak

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

> ^[^.]+.[A-z]{3,4}(?!.*.bak)

Thanks Michal Ziober for the tool.

https://regex101.com/r/HBVs2p/3

Comment: `[A-z]` contains more than just letters, have a look at an ASCII table to see what is present between `Z` and `a`